# How to add media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

i have a website
i am using CSS Reset its working good for big sized monitors
but its not working for some monitors and for mobile phones
here's the Website
i want to know which media queries i add and how to add them in my website
thanks indeed.

and here's the CSS Reset

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

I hope someone helps me guyz;)

Comment: Try Googling for any of the hundreds if not thousands of tutorials and examples.

Comment: And please write sentence ended by dots. Your question is very uncunfortable to read as such. You should write more that one very long and hard to understand sentence and explain in detail what you are trying to do otherwise we won't be able to help and consequently you will be very frustrated because we won't help you at all so please rephrase your question so that we have a chance to understand it ! Am I clear ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and i will edit it soon
can you make my website responsive? and i can pay you

Answer (score 0):

Here are good tutorial for this, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
http://cssmediaqueries.com/
it is like
    !-- CSS media query on a link element -->

```
<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .facet_sidebar {
display: none;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: so i should add this code?
because i am so sorry i dont understand

Comment: no this a type , how we write that, you should probably look for tutorial, and read the doc first, that i suggested.

Comment: okay btw can you tell me if the page displays correctly on your monitor?
and tell me if it displays incorrectly on any kind of monitors?

Comment: incorrect, i don't hope position of search box is good. media queries are written for multiple resolution and orientation so that one site can work in mobile,pc,tablet etc.

Comment: can you make my website responsive?
i can pay you !

Comment: talk on my emailid written in my profile. i can do that and send me time when we can chat over gtalk.